# Node.js While run this small js file it gives the following error

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs=require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.txt',function(err,data){
    if(err) 
        console.log(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log('Program ended');
```

node nblock.js

*****gives following error******

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>   at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\projects\text\nblock.js:5:19)
>   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
> ```

Comment: I'm 1000% sure `data` is `undefined` on your second `console.log`.

Comment: Does `console.log(err)`  log an error right before that  `TypeError:`?

Comment: Use `else` statement after `if` and `console.log(data.toString())` in `else`. First don't use `toString()` see what `data` is before performing any operation. And You are not able to read `input.txt` file thats only reason `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: To ensure you have the correct location for the file, trying using `fs.readFile(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'your/file/path))` where `your/file/path'` is a description of your text file's location relative to where you ran your script.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the error try to return if there is an error and in this way the lines after the `if` statement wont be executed.

```
var fs=require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.txt',function(err,data){
    if(err) 
        return console.log(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log('Program ended');
```

Answer (score 0):

So the program works for me when I have the text file 'input.txt' in the same directory as the program itself. You probably don't have this file in the same directory, you could add;

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (!data) { // Check if we have retrieved any data
    console.log('There is no file, ', err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log('Program ended');
```

This actually checks if there is anything before attempted to run the `toString()` method on a potentially undefined variable `data`.